# Report portal io container reportportal_db-script_1 | image migrations:5.6.0 exits as soon as after starting

Tags: reportportal

After i launch the report portal by issuing

```
docker-compose -p reportportal up -d --force-recreate
Recreating reportportal_ui_1            ... done
Recreating reportportal_minio_1         ... done
Recreating reportportal_uat_1           ... done
Recreating reportportal_gateway_1       ... done
Recreating reportportal_postgres_1      ... done
Recreating reportportal_rabbitmq_1      ... done
Recreating reportportal_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Recreating reportportal_index_1            ... done
Recreating reportportal_analyzer_train_1   ... done
Recreating reportportal_analyzer_1         ... done
Recreating reportportal_metrics-gatherer_1 ... done
Recreating reportportal_db-scripts_1       ... done
Recreating reportportal_jobs_1             ... done
Recreating reportportal_api_1              ... done
```

once all the containers are started , the reportportal_db-scripts_1 container exits

```
reportportal/migrations:5.6.0                          "/entrypoint.sh up"      58 seconds ago       Exited (0) 57 seconds ago                                                           reportportal_db-scripts_1


reportportal % docker container logs reportportal_db-scripts_1
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for postgres:5432
wait-for-it.sh: postgres:5432 is available after 0 seconds
no change
```

When manually tried i get below message

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh reportportal/migrations:5.6.0
/ # ./wait-for-it.sh localhost:80
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for localhost:80
wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for localhost:80
```

Answer (score 1):

It's functioning as intended: Exit after completion.

The `migrations` service contains scripts for data creation and transformation. If it completes its work correctly, it will exit.